# Can't fetch anything- WSL for windows 10,Trying to install environment for cLion

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix

I downloaded WSL ubuntu 18.04 for windows 10, and ran it as administrator.
I am trying to install the environment to work with cLion using 
[this tutorial](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/CLION/WSL+dev+environment+configuration)

I wanted to check my ssh connection so I wrote:

```
ssh user@localhost -p 22
```

But got the following error:

```
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
```

I've had many errors trying to fix this, most of them were" Failed to fetch", and "Connection refused".

I read somewhere at StackOverflow to uninstall ssh and then reinstall it.

The uninstallation went fine however when I tried to reinstall it with:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

and get the following errors:

```
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 openssh-client amd64 1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.4
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 openssh-client amd64 1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.4
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssh/openssh-client_7.2p2-4ubuntu2.4_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

So I am having trouble even to re-install ssh.

Would appreciate some help here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it seams the firewall in destination machine or yours is activated and prevent making connection, first check the firewall status, if it's activated, turn it off, then try again, it the connection established by disabling firewall, try to add rule into your ip table to get permission then reactive firewall.

Comment: did you turn it off in both sides? client and server? can you ping destination host?

Comment: I turned it off via windows settings.
I am a noob at this.
What do you mean by client and server?
could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: server is the machine you try to connect to it, the fire wall on the server may prevent outside connection on it's 22 port, the server admin must define rule on the server machine to grant you connection permission. first try to ping server ip by this command => >ping <server-ip> for example 'ping 192.168.1.1' where 192.168.1.1 is your server, if the server is unreachable, ask your network admin to check your machine connectivity in network,

Comment: else if the server were reachable, try to make a tel net connection on port 22 => telnet 192.168.1.1 22 . if the connection is refused, ask your server admin to grant you the access to 22 port of server host

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem within our company network. I wasn´t able to connect to the outer world e.g. with `sudo apt-get update`

I needed to add our companies proxy in /etc/apt/apt.conf with adding this line:

`Acquire::http::Proxy "http://[proxy-ip]:[port]";`

For me, the apt.conf file didn´t exit at all, so I just created it.

After that, I was able to connect to the outer world and the installation of openssh-server went fine.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but for whoever is still stuck on this issue, just go to the /etc/resolv.conf and comment out the search lan line.

Comment: If possible please explain why/how this helps. It'd also be nice to state the exact line.

Comment: I'm not an expert at linux but I'm guessing this forces apt to search only in the underlying network but I'm nowhere near sure. Also, the line is "search lan", I searched everywhere for a solution and when I removed it (it was the last line in the file), everything worked like a charm. Hope this helps.